# Android - Setting background on canvas using PNG file

Tags: android, png, resolution, android-canvas, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to set a .PNG file as background on `Canvas` in my app. I've made an image 480 x 800 and used this method:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
                  R.drawable.image_1), 0, 0, null);
```

I've started an emulator (WVGA800) but my image looks greater than screen of the device.

How do I resize this image or what kind of methods should I use to make this image well-matched.

Secondly, is there any way to make backgrounds like this universal for devices with different screen resolutions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You better get your Device size before setting your image into your canvas. And, set that height&width to your image. Hope that'll help you.

Comment: If it's a static image, you could set the background of the view who's canvas you are drawing on then call super.onDraw() before your drawing methods. Using scaleType you can let Android take care of the resizing for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where did you put the image? if it's in the drawable or the drawable-mdpi , it will be larger than what you've told , since WVGA800 has a high density (hdpi) .

even if you put it on the drawable-hdpi folder , it will work for WVGA800 , but it might not show well on other devices , which have different resolutions and aspect ratio .

you need to handle the scaling and keeping of aspect ratio (if you wish) . otherwise , you will have the same problems on other devices.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one ...

*Set bitmap*

```
Bitmap mFinalbitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_1);
```

*Resize bitmap as per your width and height*

```
mFinalbitmap= resizeImage(mFinalbitmap, width ,height);
```

*Set Canvas of Bitmap*

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mFinalbitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

Resize Function: As per maintain x and y of image

```
public Bitmap resizeImage(Bitmap image,int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    Bitmap resizedImage = null;
    try {
        int imageHeight = image.getHeight();


        if (imageHeight > maxHeight)
            imageHeight = maxHeight;
        int imageWidth = (imageHeight * image.getWidth())
                / image.getHeight();

        if (imageWidth > maxWidth) {
            imageWidth = maxWidth;
            imageHeight = (imageWidth * image.getHeight())
                    / image.getWidth();
        }

        if (imageHeight > maxHeight)
            imageHeight = maxHeight;
        if (imageWidth > maxWidth)
            imageWidth = maxWidth;


        resizedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, imageWidth,
                imageHeight, true);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resizedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:
declare static Bitmap in your class:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
```

setup the resized bitmap, for example you want resized bitmap to 100x100:

```
    private void initBitmap(){
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.Your_bitmap);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100,100,true);
    }
```

and call method in constructor