# Android - Drawing bar graphs with patterns

Tags: android, user-interface, graph, android-drawable, rectangles

I currently have an app that draws bar graphs using red and blue rectangles.  However, to make it more print-friendly (particularly for monochrome printers), I would like to know, what is the correct way to add a pattern to these graphs?

I assume I would have to use an image Drawable, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a canvas, it works just like the html5 canvas, its like a board where you can add shapes, these shapes can have colors, sizes and formats.

Check some charts libraries examples on [this site](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=chart).

Changing view background:

The custom view will have these methods:

```
this.setBackgroundDrawable();
this.setBackgroundResource();
```

You will probablu want to call them on onDraw.

Another approach is definning a bitmap to the canvas itself:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mbitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

[Check out this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765300/android-setting-background-on-canvas-using-png-file)

Comment: Each bar already has its own canvas, so I would like to know how can I add a pattern to them.

Comment: Sorry, i was thinking of java pattern to let the user customize the graph.